# Quill can't get toolbar to render correctly when instantiating with webpack

Tags: javascript, webpack, quill

I can't get Quill to render toolbar correctly I read their [docs](https://quilljs.com/guides/adding-quill-to-your-build-pipeline) and check [webpack example](https://github.com/quilljs/webpack-example).

Added webpack aliases,

```
resolve: {
    alias: {
      'parchment': utils.resolve('node_modules/parchment/src/parchment.ts'),
      'quill$': utils.resolve('node_modules/quill/quill.js'),
    }
}
```

then created Quill export file like so

````
`quill-build.js`
```js
import Quill from 'quill/core';

import Toolbar from 'quill/modules/toolbar';
import Snow from 'quill/themes/snow';

import Bold from 'quill/formats/bold';
import Italic from 'quill/formats/italic';
import Header from 'quill/formats/header';

Quill.register({
  'modules/toolbar': Toolbar,
  'themes/snow': Snow,
  'formats/bold': Bold,
  'formats/italic': Italic,
  'formats/header': Header,
});

export default Quill;
```
````

Imported it in my component and when attaching it to html element here is what I get

[image]

This is what I get inside chrome devtools when inspecting this tag.

[image]

If I import quil.min.js from cdn it renders everything correctly, but that is useless if I can't customize my build and remove unnecessary elements.

Did anyone had success doing that, can someone help me with this, please?

Comment: Did you add html-loader to your webpack? Can you post your webpack.conf.js?

Comment: https://paste.laravel.io/bcf04012-bba6-4a68-a775-578d37f94534 this is first part of my config, this one contains my rulesi https://paste.laravel.io/0104981b-dac4-4e96-a754-7f52bd6107b7 ncluding html-loader, this one just utils that use path  https://paste.laravel.io/87db74fa-1864-4f32-a982-2fa29f478671

Comment: It does not look like you are using html-loader in SVGs. Take a look at the example repo webpack config https://github.com/quilljs/webpack-example/blob/master/webpack.conf.js

Answer (score 1):

I know that's an old issue but as it is still a problem the solution is to use: https://v4.webpack.js.org/loaders/svg-inline-loader/
instead of the html-loader from the webpack quill example